# Can I duplicate parameter tensor whose values are the same across duplicates while training?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

So let's say I have an input vector of size 100. Specifically, the input vector is size [50 + 50]. Then I want to create a parameter tensor of size [50 x 2] that is applied to the first 50 inputs and second 50 inputs. such that we get a vector of size [2 + 2] afterward. I want the first 50 inputs and last 50 inputs of the input vector to be multiplied by the same [50 x 2] parameter tensor and that this remains true while parameter updating. Can you "duplicate" a parameter tensor like so or is there a way to program this? I'm not sure if the ".clone()" function does what I want..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can define an operation one time and then apply it multiple time in a forward:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    self.layer1 = ...
    self.layer2 = ...


def forward(self, input1, input2):
    o1 = self.layer1(input1)
    o2 = self.layer1(input2)
    return self.layer2(input1+input2)
```

And here for example the layer1 parameters are used twice, you don't need to duplicate them juste to call them multiple time after defining them

Comment: Oh interesting. I did not think of this. Then when the neural network optimizes the parameters of 'self.layer1', will it take into account both the changes received from input1 and input2 simultaneously?